# How to access AngularJS directive Form fields into parent controller

Tags: angularjs

I created following form as a angular directive and try to access the firstname from parent controller.
Please help me or guide me how to access directive form fields from inside MainCtrl.

**HTML**

```
 <pre>
      {{filter-frm| json}}
 </pre> 

 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <userform></userform>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope){
    console.log($scope.filterForm.firstname) //How to get this ?
};

.directive('userform', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { formCtrl: '=' }
        template: '<div>'
            + '<form id="filterForm" ng-submit="login()">'
            + '<input name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstName">'
            + '</form> '
            + '</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, iAttrs) {
            var form = element.find('form');
            scope.formCtrl = form.controller('form');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `name` attribute to your form in your directive template, you will be able to access it via `scope.formName`. It should also bind the input fields values via `scope.formName.fooInput`.

In your case, adding `name="filterForm"` should do the trick:

```js
template: '<div>'
    + '<form id="filterForm" name="filterForm" ng-submit="login()">'
    + '<input name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstName">'
    + '</form> '
    + '</div>',
```

Now you should be able to access `scope.filterForm` in the parent controller.

> **Param:** name (optional); **Type:** string; **Details:** Name of the form. If specified, the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name.

from [ngForm doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the values of the field to variables of your controller's model.
To do that, you have to expose the form fields as attributes of your directive.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/#!/guide/directive and how to use the scope field.